# Extract one occurrence of a pattern from file

Tags: regular-expression

I have large file containing logs similar to one shown below. I would like to find all transactions(TR#) that were affected with the error. I need to extract one occurrence of each TR# ID.

How could I go about it?

```
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
```

Required output:

```
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
```

Comment: Did the final line of input get truncated? is the error code meant to be 704 there as well not 70?

Comment: @steeldriver. That is typo. It is always 704.

Comment: Are the timestamps really all the same? if not, which one do you want to print (if any)?

Comment: @steeldriver No. The date is same but not the time stamp. Getting out the first one should do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple to do in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'c[$5]++==1' file 
Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
```

Or, in Perl:

```
$ perl -ane '$k{$F[4]}++==1 && print' file 
Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
```

The above assume that the number before each `TR#ID` is part of the ID. If the numbers can change but you only need one of them, use this instead:

```
$ awk -F'[:.]' 'c[$7]++==1' file
```

or

```
$ perl -F'[:.]' -ane '$k{$F[6]}++==1 && print' file
```

Answer (score 3):

To get and print the first occurrence of each message, try

```
awk '! m[$5] {m[$5]=$0} END{for (e in m) print m[e]}'
```

I made the timestamps in your example sequential in order to test it (and also corrected the final truncated error value):

```
$ awk '! m[$5] {m[$5]=$0} END{for (e in m) print m[e]}' tr2.log
Apr 30 16:51:27.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
Apr 30 16:51:31.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
```

With thanks to @terdon

Comment: Why not just `awk 'c[$5]++==1' file `? Am I missing something?

Comment: Doh! thanks - I will simplify my answer accordingly. My brain hurts (the OP kept changing the question...)

Comment: OK, I thought you might be anticipating a complication that my answer would miss :) Oh man, I just saw the edit history. Poor you.

Comment: Actually yours is still simpler - why not post it as a separate answer? I always forget about the `1` default print action.

Comment: I did post it. [It's right here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129215/22222).

Comment: Oops... off to get more coffee... and upvote you ;)

Comment: Sorry folks for editing the post often. I will now try out the suggestions provided. Thanks much!

Comment: Both worked well!. All solutions for the questions works :-) I am  up voting all and choosing @terdon's. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by piping easy tasks to be done:

```
grep 'Error Code: 704' test_log | uniq | less
```

The `grep` command will only select the lines containing the string "Error Code: 704". The `uniq` command will only keep one of each element. The sign ">" will use the standard output and send it to the file named "new_file"

Probably there are better ways of doing it which I don't know yet

Comment: The basic idea is sound, but the output doesn't match what the poster asked for.

Comment: @3nirque. Thanks for your answer. Actually each log statement as some details like time and date precede 'TR#' I have edited the post with that detail.

Comment: I just removed the awk and sed commands. It works nicely in your exemple. In this case if the time stamp is different you might find some lines that contain the same error code

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perl script that does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#Read each line
while ($line = <>) {
  # Extract the transaction ID by looking for the text TR followed by digits
  ($trid) = $line =~ /.*(TR#\d+).*/ ;
  # If we've not seen the ID before, print it out
  unless ($trids{$trid}) {
    print $line;
  }
  # Remember the ID so we don't print it out again
  $trids{$trid} = 1;
}
```

When I call it using your input, this is what I get:

```
temeraire:ul jenny$ ./extract.pl in.txt 
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#14. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
    Apr 30 16:51:29.574 application.crit: [6104]:TR#238. Transaction send can not be sent. Error Code: 704
```

Answer (score 1):

Through GNU `sed`, stolen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444433/3297613) SO answer,

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' file
```